# sql prepared statement and java

Tags: java, sql

I am using a Prepared statement which works fine e.g. if I run

```
Select * from users where name = 'john' and sName = sName
```

I get a list of everyone whose name is john. However if I execute the query

```
Select * from users where name= ? and sName = ?
```

the query doesn't return anything, I think it is because it adds the '' to the string being passed?

```
//n value is passed through GUI interface.
String s = "sName";
PreparedStatement prep = "Select * from users where name= ? and sName= ?";
prep.setString(1, n);
prep.setString(2, s);
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Do you have users with surname of "surname"?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this code doesn't compile since a `PreparedStatement` isn't  a `String`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, note that in

```
Select * from users where name = 'john' and sName = sName
```

`sName=sName` just do nothing if `sName` is a column name or does not work.

Then, when you have a statement

```
Select * from users where name= ? and surname = ?
```

You have to set both parameters with `PreparedStatement#setXxx()` methods. Since you set the 2d parameter with `String s = "surname"`, you will fetch all users that have a surname value which is the string `"surname"`, and what ever name you set in the first parameter. It looks unlikely, and this is why you get no result.

Note1: with this statement you cannot fetch users based only on their name. You have to define another statement, e.g.

```
Select * from users where name= ?
```

Note2: if you have users in the database, *without* a surname, i.e. the `surname` value is `NULL`, then you can use the first statement with

```
// n variable contains the name
String query = "Select * from users where name= ? and surname = ?";
PreparedStatement prep = connection.prepareStatement(query);
prep.setString(1, n);
prep.setNull(2, Types.VARCHAR);
ResultSet rs = prep.executeQuery();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Abbe. Just to clarify I use the 1st query <pre> Select * from users where name = 'john' and sName = sName<code> in mysql and it works ( it brings up all the users whose name is john regardless of the value stored in sName), the 2nd query is the one I use in Java, which is where I am stuck. I basically want the query to return all values in the table where the name = n and sName = s or if s is empty then sName then return all the people who have the name n - hope it makes sense. p.s. I realised I typed surname instead of sName on the 2nd qry, so I just made both sName

Comment: We are ok on the first point (when I said it does nothing, I meant putting `sName=sName` is like writing `and true`). I understand what you are trying to do in the Java code, but unfortunately, you wont be able to use the same trick with the `<colName>=<colName>`. With the preparedStatement, you set a `String` value which contains the column name but it's not the column: the query will end up with something like `... and sName='sName'`, which is not the same thing as `... and sName=sName`.  Then, as I said in the answer, if you need to filter only on name, you need another statement.

Answer (score 2):

You are doing it wrong.
You must first create a variable of **PreparedStatement** and initialize it with the query then execute it using **executeQuery()** method of **PreparedStatement**.

It would look like ...

```
String s = "surname";
    String query = "Select * from users where name= ? and surname = ?";
    PreparedStatement prep = connection.prepareStatement(query);
    prep.setString(1, n);
    prep.setString(2, s);
    ResultSet rs = prep.executeQuery();
```

Comment: my bad I should have posted more of my code - that is what I have - but when s is passed as a string it doesn't return anything - i suspect it is because of the way PreparedStatements work

Comment: When you are executing query without use of **PreparedStatememt** the column in where clause is **sname**. And when you are doing it with **PreparedStatememt**, you are using **surname** column. What is the column name in table?

Answer (score 0):

use executeQuery() and not execute()